# Preventing insertion of a duplicate account record but merging that data into master account

Tags: findduplicates

So Basically I wanted to check if the new account which i am trying to add is duplicate or not. if it's duplicate, I wanted to prevent that insertion and merge that account's data to the master account which is already in database. I am putting few matching fields to check duplicates.
Also i wanted to do it with Before insert/update trigger.
Problem is when i use addError method, it's preventing all the DMLs including the master account update as well. is there any way by which I can only prevent duplicate account insertion but allow updating master account.

Answer (score 0):

You can't both add an error and commit changes to the database. You can either use an after insert/after update trigger to merge duplicates (users may experience an error when the page loads), asynchronous Apex to merge after the record is committed, or you can use addError or a Duplicate Rule to block duplicates. In other words, what you're asking for is not possible. There are solutions, but your specific request is not possible.